# Open creating file with weird permissionss

Tags: c

At first I was using

```
fd = open(outputfile,O_WRONLY | O_TRUNC | O_CREAT);
```

which was giving me random file permissions but now I am using

```
fd = open(outputfile,O_WRONLY | O_TRUNC | O_CREAT, 0666);
```

this code is produces file exact same file permissions but they are weird.
I actually want -rw-rw-rw- but I am getting:

```
--w---x--T 1 root root    21 Apr 24 13:02 fasdfas
```

and on one of the other system:

```
--w--wx--T 1 s8771-26 s8771-26    21 Apr 24 22:09 test1
--w--wx--T 1 s8771-26 s8771-26    21 Apr 24 22:09 test2
--w--wx--T 1 s8771-26 s8771-26    21 Apr 24 22:09 test3
--w--wx--T 1 s8771-26 s8771-26    21 Apr 24 22:09 test4


#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    int fd = open(argv[1],O_WRONLY | O_TRUNC | O_CREAT, 0666);
    dup2(fd,1);
    printf("TEST");
    return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: You didn’t specify the third argument to `open()` which is required with `O_CREAT`.  The third argument specifies the permissions, which will be modified by the `umask` value.

Comment: `open()` will set the file mode only if it creates the file.  Are you sure you're not seeing modes set when the earlier, buggy version of your program created them?  Be sure you remove the files before running the program to see the modes that will be set when they are created.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I am positive I am removed them. I wrote a simple program again and I get same permissions. I added my program in post.

Comment: No, as far as I can tell you *didn't* update the question to contain your program.  But we do need you to provide a [mcve].  Perhaps your whole program would suit, if it is very simple, but in any case please do try to present something minimal that nevertheless demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Sorry. I just updated it. Thanks

Comment: The program you've presented behaves for me exactly as I would expect (on CentOS Linux 7).  When it creates a new file, it assigns a mode formed by applying the process's umask to the specified mode.  In my case, that produces an actual mode of 0644.

Comment: @JohnBollinger is it creating file with rw-rw-rw permission?

Comment: Are you sure you're running the version of the program you present?  You did not, for example, forget to recompile after updating the source?

Comment: @JohnBollinger Yes I am running the program I posted here.

Comment: For me, your program is creating the file with the expected permissions.  As I said, the process's umask factors in to that, so in my particular case, my expectation is 0644 (rw-r--r--), and that's what I see.

Comment: Add the `O_EXCL` flag - `open(argv[1],O_WRONLY | O_TRUNC | O_CREAT | O_EXCL, 0666);` and emit an error message that either uses `perror()` or includes `errno` and/or the output from `strerror()` if the `open()` fails.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Thank you. You were right I was using 666 instead of 0666. Thank you so much!

Comment: @P.P. Yes, because I think I didnt press ctrl+s correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed by @JohnBollinger in comment I didnt save the file correctly and I was using 666 instead of 0666